# Multiline label in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, ios8

I have updated my device iOS to iOS 8 and now multiline label is not working. Its displaying very weird screen shot attached.

So please can you suggest me the solution.

I already set Number of lines =0 and it was working perfect in ios 7.
Not using Autolayout and story board.

[image: multiline label]

Comment: try `label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`

Answer (score 0):

This code help you.It works fine me.Edit your code according to need

```
 UILabel *problem = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 100, 200, 100)];
    problem.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    problem.text=@"Please use this code it may help you it works fine for me";
    problem.numberOfLines=0;
  [self.view addSubview:problem];
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, this fix doesn't work if you don't use all of it:

1. Set the line break mode to word wrapping (if that's the affect you want).
2. Set the number of lines to 0 (I had it set to 2 and it still didn't work).

Not sure if something changed here with the introduction with iOS 8 but my previous code (just setting the number of lines to 2) was working great on iOS 7.

Anyone else face a similar issue?

Answer (score -4):

Do you use a custom font?Try changing the font.